# Eclipse IDE not using proper fonts

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, fonts

How can I change Eclipse font to use the exactly the same fonts as NetBeans?

Technically, both IDEs use the same font (Consolas on Windows) but produce different results.
Eclipse fonts are smaller, parts of the text are bold and the fonts seem more anti-aliased.

The problem appears both in Windows 7 and Gnome3-based Linux and the question concerns both those platforms. For me, the Linux platform is even more important, since it runs on a 12.1 inch screen laptop, with the bold font hurting code clarity.

Here's a screenshot from Eclipse and NetBeans on Windows 7:

[image: Eclipse and NetBeans font differences]

Edit: Of course, using Consolas 10 in NetBeans produces only smaller font, without the effects seen in Eclipse.

Comment: I think this is a Swing vs SWT font rendering issue.  Don't know of a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control font style (such as getting rid of bold if you don't like it) under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring. There are some additional links on that preferences page to other places where you can configure fonts in Eclipse.

Outside of that, Eclipse uses native OS behavior for text presentation (such as anti-aliasing). NetBeans, which uses Swing uses Java's text presentation. You should observe Eclipse text looking identical to other native text editors on the same platform. Depending on the OS, you will usually have some configurability over anti-aliasing and other text presentation aspects at OS-level.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wrongly assumed the syntax coloring options were defined by General -> Appearance -> Font and Colors.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing them both to the old font used under windows xp. Courier New 10. Solved the problem for me.